# Block Chain in RxKotlin and Proceed

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I have a chaining operation in my application, Where i have a list of some data, i will iterate through the list with `iteratable observable` once the iteration completes, i will perform some other operation which does not depends on the previous list, so what i need is in between these two operation i need to block(or barrier) until the first completes and proceed with second one.

Example

```
Observable.fromIterable(listOf("A","B","C","D"))
          .map{
            doSomeTask(it)
          } 
   // I need a blocking here, once this iteration completes i will proceed with the below task, but i don't need of toList() to block since i don't want the data,       
          .map{
            doSomeOtherTask()
          }
```

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `doOnNext` if you want to propagate each of the values, or `doOnComplete` when you want to do something at the end of the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is below:

```
Observable.fromIterable(listOf("A", "B", "C", "D"))
        .subscribeBy(
            onNext = {
                doSomeTask(it)
            },
            onComplete = {
                doSomeOtherTask()
            }
        )
```

This way you'll achieve the expected result. Cheers!